# Как задать нужный мне фон для прогресс бара?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

У меня есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я хочу сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это можно реализовать?

`<controls:MetroProgressBar EllipseDiameter="7" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="#3F85C4" />`

Comment: а можно увидеть код для MetroProgressBar?

Comment: @Monomax Он из Mahaps.metro библиотеки

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что сделать подобное, изменением одного `Foreground` - не возможно? Тут надо переопределять стили самого контрола как минимум...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да,конечно,поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Можно сделать элемент в элементе...велосипед конечно, но вам может подойти. Первый элемент почти не будет видно, и будет казаться что это акантовка внутреннего элемента.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Можете пример c кодом предложить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается очень просто,как оказалось.
Вот пример кода,который помог мне решить эту проблему.

```
<controls:MetroProgressBar EllipseDiameter="7" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="#3F85C4" >
                            <controls:MetroProgressBar.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </controls:MetroProgressBar.OpacityMask>
                        </controls:MetroProgressBar>
```